# Mask Text Input

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

Hey I'm trying to make a simple input text something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" maxlength="4" size="4" placeholder="____">
```

Now on the frontend I want that placeholder to remain until a user types all the characters.

For example:

```
1___
12__
123_
1234
```

Is this clear? 
Thank you for your help

EDIT: Let me make this more clear.
I want the placeholder or something emulating a placeholder to remain visible until all characters are typed! Which means that when I type a character it just doesn't disappear. It inserts an underscore on characters that weren't typed yet.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "masking" function. There are a multitude of options if you google "javascript input mask" (fair warning, most of them will involve jQuery or some other dependency)

Comment: Thank you BLSully I'll look into that. EDIT: Yep I think this Is it, Since my english was not that good I didn't know the correct name.

Comment: As also suggested by @BLSully, here's a jQuery masking plugin I've used in the past: [http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect you're looking for a masking solution... what you're trying to do via the `placeholder` attribute is just plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. My english isn't great And I didn't know the correct name. Thanks and I think I can do it now.

Comment: This seems like a very unusual piece of UX.
Assuming that the goal is to reinforce to the user that 4 characters are required, how about using four separate textboxes for your input, and using JavaScript to move focus between them as the user types?

Comment: @RichardEv: are you suggesting that if I need to create an input for a US Social Security Number there should be 9 separate inputs? =0\

Comment: @BLSully - I was only considering the scenario in the question; 4 characters.

Comment: @RichardEv: sorry, bad choice of words on my part. Not my question, just my observation. I believe that in general it's a poor choice to specify multiple inputs for an atomic piece of data. If the OP needs to input a 4-character PO Number, again, 4 individual inputs seems like a very awkward UX design

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders do not work like this by default because it's a bad idea. Take this situation, for example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something here!"/>
```

If the user begins typing "Hello, world!", the process would be:

```
"Hype something here!"
"Hepe something here!" ...
"Hellosomething here!" ...
"Hello world!ng here!"
```

This would be fine if your placeholder was barely visible, but for the most part this would just be ugly and possibly confusing too - the user may be lead to believe that they must type exactly what's put as the placeholder or they may try to clear the input completely with no success.

Placeholders simply give text input elements dummy content *until* real content has been added.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to add that the correct thing to name what I was trying to do is mask the input and when I googled it it gave me an answer. Thank you for your help.